# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property toLowerCase of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-security

How can I include the token within all your Ajax requests using jQuery and spring security?

At the moment I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Javascript:

```
function editUser(data) {

var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
var ctx = location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/"));
var dataObject = JSON.stringify({ 'username': data });

$.ajax({
      url: ctx+'/users/edit',
      type: 'POST',
      beforeSend: function(xhr){
          xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
      },
      data: data
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editUser(@RequestParam("username") String username) {

    System.out.println(username);
    return "users/edit";
}
```

toLowerCase function is in jQuery

```
// Caches the header
                setRequestHeader: function( name, value ) {
                    var lname = name.toLowerCase();
                    if ( !state ) {
                        name = requestHeadersNames[ lname ] = requestHeadersNames[ lname ] || name;
                        requestHeaders[ name ] = value;
                    }
                    return this;
                },
```

Comment: I don't see any use of `toLowerCase` in any of the code you posted. The error is happening somewhere else.

Comment: @Barmar Please see my edit

Comment: The error indicates that `header` is undefined.

Comment: I added these in the head of my page and this has fixed the issue `<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>`
 `<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>`

Comment: Naturally. Your code copies the contents of those meta tags into the AJAX header. Of course it doesn't work if you don't have the tags.

Comment: and of course I posted a question to stack overflow. It seems a place of teachers not helpers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either make sure that the page always has `<meta name="_csrf" content="something">` and `<meta name="_csrf_header" content="something">` tags, or have your AJAX code check that the values exist before trying to set the header:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    if (header && token) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    }
}
```